# remove top border tabbar without clipping to bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I've got a `UITabBarController` with a `UITabBar` that looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove the top border, but I don't want the subview (the image) to `clipsToBounds`, since it has a little 'top'. How do I remove the top border while maintaining the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the background image and the shadow image like so:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: Thanks! I already figured it out but forgot about this question :3